# symfony2 pull from DB right after flush() not possible?

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine, flush

(SEE LAST LINE OF QUESTION FOR SOLUTION)

Is there a time limit for when I can pull a flushed value out from the DB?

Because when I add an entity and flush it into DB like this...

```
        //Persist the entity and flush it to DB
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        $helper->log('success', 'Innehållet <strong>'. $entity->getTitle() .'</strong> (id:<strong>'. $entity->getId() .'</strong>) har skapats i '.$place.$purified. $videoMessage);

        $helper->generateManifestForAll( $currentCompany->getId() );
        $helper->log('success', 'Manifest & slideData updated');
```

And try to read it back inside the $helper->generateManifestForAll() it doesn't exist yet. If I repeat the process by adding another entity, then the first entity is included (but not the second, naturally. Not until I create a third entity...).

If I trigger the generateManifestForAll() manually afterward that also works to have the new entity included, so it seems to be a problem of them sitting inside the same controller or something..?

------------------ UPDATE --------------------------

Could it have something to do with the fact that generateManifestForAll() is inside a service?

First I instantiate the service object $helper (which has an entityManager injected into it), then I use $em->flush() inside my controller. And then finally I run the generateManifestForAll() which pulls data out.

I could paste all the code but it is so much, I thought maybe you could detect an error already in the concept here?

-------------------- Another Update -------------------

These two debug loops give me the exact same output.

```
//debug
echo "beforeFlush<br/>";
$data = $entity->getContainer()->getContent();
foreach($data as $d) {
echo $d->getTitle().'<br/>';
}

//Persist the entity and flush it to DB
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
        $em->refresh($entity);

//debug
echo " ";
echo "<br/><br/>afterFlush<br/>";
$data = $entity->getContainer()->getContent();
foreach($data as $d) {
echo $d->getTitle().'<br/>';
}
die;
```

AND THE FINAL SOLUTION - IN MY CASE, OBVIOUSLY CALL REFRESH ON

```
        $em->refresh($entity->getContainer());
```

SINCE THAT'S THE ENTITY I'M LOOPING FROM.

Comment: If you have a proper setter for your entity when you create a new instance the `$entity` is a valid object and without `$em->refresh($entity)` you have access to the object and values; I think you need to `unset($entity)` after all the process is done for each entity, so that anytime you have a fresh entity object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

If this not works, try this:

```
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
$em->refresh();
```

By the way i suggest you to use a DoctrineEventListener to keep logs.

See:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html
[preUpdate and postUpdate events not triggered on Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357855/preupdate-and-postupdate-events-not-triggered-on-doctrine-2)

I know that documentations are a little confusing.

Comment: Didn't help in my case. Also, $em->refresh() required an argument, so I put my $entity in there like: $em->refresh($entity). Not working though.

Comment: Refresh method must work (it reloads the entity from db). Did you try to dump your $entity? After using refresh?

Comment: Ah, in my case I have to call refresh on the parent entity (referenced by $entity)... got it.

Comment: When you call an entity directly from it's namespace (entity object itself / new SampleEntity()) it's working with no problem. I'm glad you solved your problem.